# Can’t figure out how to remove cartridge of single handle tub faucet

Tags: faucet, bathtub, cartridge

We have a leaking bathtub faucet and need to replace the cartridge but we cant’t figure out how to remove the casing (estachian?) around it. I don’t know the brand or model number. Everything is stuck from the hard water. We’ve already replaced the faucet but that didn’t fix it. Any help is much appreciated!!  [image][image]

Comment: @jsotola we tried to clean it up, but everything is “cemented” on there. This is why I’m asking for help to get the casing off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stem is held in place by a u-shaped piece of metal.  If you scrape through enough crud, you'll find the bottom of it on the outside of the metal cylinder.  Pull it out with a pair of pliers.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkZad_sHQkQ about 0:50 in is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you. We got it out with a lot of force—now looking at a $975 estimate to replace the shower valve. Plumber said he probably wouldn’t have been able to get it out and we would have the same repair amount.